# Producer does not put messages in default resource file (BusinessLayer.ResX)

Tags: codefluent

My application supports two languages: Dutch and Flemish (which is spoken in Belgium). I want all Dutch messages in the default resource file (BusinessLayer.ResX) and all Flemish messages in the BusinessLayer.nl_BE.ResX file, because the default fallback language must be Dutch if no Flemish message is found. How can I accomplish this?

I tried specifying no culture for the Dutch messages and no project culture, but the BOM producer keeps producing an empty default .ResX file and puts all Dutch messages in the .nl-NL.ResX file. Why does it think that messages must be put into the .nl-NL.ResX file? I don't specify anywhere in my xml project files that the Dutch culture must be used...

Comment: It seems that I have to specify cultureName="" in the cf:project element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to specify the Culture property at the model project level.
See complete answer and model/code sample provided to your company by the private support channel on same subject, especially how to provide the related global or property/entity rules specific messages for all cultures.